# Bootstrap and IE 8 = disaster

Tags: javascript, css, windows, internet-explorer-8

I have been doing quite some research on how to make Bootstrap work with IE 8, but it still looks like this:

[image: Internet Explorer 8 showing my bootstrap form]

**What I did so far:**

1. Insert into the `<head>`

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   ```
2. Insert respond.js

-> But still the same. Is the problem the subdomain? Or is my IE 8 just too old? Funny is I tried to update it, but could not get it updated. I'm a Mac guy, maybe I need some extra degrees for that... Microsoft only offered me IE 10/11.

URL to the form: [inday.idext.co.th](http://inday.idext.co.th)
If you wish to have a look at the PHP file: [pls click](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11792796/index.php)

Thanks so much in advance, I'm really lost with this browser. :-(

Comment: Not sure if this will help but it might be worth a shot. In older versions of IE you can only have a limited number of css selectors in one css file. Also you can only include so many css files. You may have too many css selectors in one file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Bootstrap version 4.0.0-alpha. Line 36:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

From the Bootstrap v4 docs: [Supporting Internet Explorer 8](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/browsers-devices/#supporting-internet-explorer-8)

> As of v4, Bootstrap no longer supports IE8. **If you require IE8 support, we recommend you use Bootstrap 3.** It’s still supported by our team for bugfixes and documentation changes, but no new features will be added to it.
>
> Alternatively, you may add some third party JavaScript to backfill support for IE8 to Bootstrap 4. You’ll need the following:
>
> - [The HTML5 shiv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Shiv)
> - [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)
> - [Rem unit polyfill](https://github.com/chuckcarpenter/REM-unit-polyfill)
>
> No support will be provided for this, though you may find some help from the community in [our Slack channel](https://bootstrap-slack.herokuapp.com/).

So taking their suggestions, either follow the above options to get a working solution or opt to use version 3 which is currently the stable release. Other than those solutions, I'd say you would need to hire someone extra with the required skills to help build your site as fixing everything on your product with the alpha of v4 is outside of the scope of this site.

Answer (score 0):

Add to head:

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media     queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js">    </script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js">    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: and as @Ash mentioned, use bootstrap 3 with the above.